# How can I use Jquery's Coolinput to show the hint "Enter your password" in a password field, but then use stars to hide the input when user types?

Tags: jquery, input, hide

pretty self explanatory...

Answer (score 5):

Make your password textbox of type "text":

```
<input type="text" alt="Enter Password" name="PWD" />
```

Then use the following script:

```
$(function() {
   $("input[name=PWD]")
      .focus(function() { $(this).attr("type","password"); })
      .blur(function() { 
          if ($(this).val()) // check if you entered something
             $(this).attr("type","text"); 
       })
      .coolinput();
});
```

What it does is this: when the focus is received, the textbox is changed to a password box, and when focus is lost, it returns to a normal textbox (so the hint text is readable), unless of course something was entered in the textbox.

I didn't actually test this, but if it doesn't work correctly, at least it will point you in the direction to take.

***EDIT:***

It seems you can't change the type of a text box using javascript, so here's a workaround:

```
 <input id="PWD1" name="PWD1" value="Enter password"/>
 <input id="PWD2" name="PWD2" type="password" style="display:none" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $("#PWD1").focus(function() {  $("#PWD2").show().focus(); $("#PWD1").hide(); });
   $("#PWD2").blur(function() {

     if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
             $("#PWD1").show();
             $("#PWD2").hide();
     }
   });

});
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/iniza

Comment: unfortunately type property cannot be changed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use jquery impromptu plugin, follow the link for a detailed explanation... in a nutshell, you would be using a form's standard input type password.

[Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php)

Something like this:

```
var txt = 'Enter your password:<br />
      <input type="password" id="jPassword"
      name="jPassword" value="" />';

function mycallbackform(v,m,f){
    if (v){
      $.prompt('your password is of '+ f.jPassword.length + 'characters');
    } 
}

$.prompt(txt,{
      callback: mycallbackform,
      buttons: { Accept: true, Cancel: false }
});
```

Comment: Please correct the 'impromptu' link, the right one is http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/